# RGB or Hex numbers in Googlechart - chartEditor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I am using Google-charts in my webappplication application that uses AngularJs. To let the user configure the chart options am trying to use [chartEditor](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_charteditor) class.

But i have a doubt, do we need to select only from those 80 colors in that color palette ??

what needs to be done if the user wants to use RGB numbers or Hex numbers for choosing colors ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use all HEX color, but you need to declare those colors on the init.

And, in case of the user wants to use RGB, you need to convert the RGB color to HEX format.

Comment: the chartEditor is having no such init methods right ? openDialog is the method that takes options for the chart editor but "dataSourceInput" is the only option mentioned in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#charteditor-class) . I cudn't find any such thing.. cud u pl explain ?